# Populate a struct array with unique identifier

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swifty-json

heres my scenario i got a list of services and in that list of services, one service can contain a number of properties so i created the below structs

```
    var serviceData : JSON = [
    "services": [
        [
            "id": "SERVICE ONE ID",
            "properties": [
                [
                "id": "propetyID",
                "name": "first service first property name"
                ],
                [
                    "id": "propetyID",
                    "name": "first service second property name"
                ]
            ],
            "name": "First Service"
        ],
        [
            "id": "SERVICE Two ID",
            "properties": [
                [
                "id": "propetyID",
                "name": "second service first property name"
                ],
                [
                    "id": "propetyID",
                    "name": "second service second property name"
                ]
            ],
            "name": "Second Service"
        ]
    ]   
]
struct Properties {
    var id:String
    var name:String
}
struct Services {
    var id:String
    var name:String
    var properties:[Properties]
}
var arrServices : [Services]()
```

i am using `SwiftyJSON` and created the above `json` data i want to populate the values of `arrServices` with the `serviceData` data.

and i want the service data to be unique for example the first service has two properties so the first index of the services struct array should look like in(pseudocode):

```
struct Services
    id:SERVICE ONE ID
    name:First Service
    properties: [Properties(id:"propertyID",name:"first service first property name"),Properties(id:"propertyID",name:"first service second property name")]
```

i am new to swift and i just can't wrap my head around for solving this, any suggestion and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries so you can parse it in this way:

```
 for dict in json["services"].arrayValue {

    arrServices.append(
        Services(
            id: dict["id"].stringValue,
            name: dict["name"].stringValue,
            properties: dict["properties"].arrayValue.map {
                Properties(
                    id: $0["id"].stringValue,
                    name: $0["name"].stringValue
                )
            }
        )
    )

}
```

Comment: Can't wait to try this out...i am off working hours now...i will let you know...Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: ok i tried it, but what if i wanted to iterate on the first index of the services array something like this for dict in json["services"][0].arrayValue but in this case i think the .arrayValues wont work

Comment: You can set your dict as the first member of the array in this way:

`guard let dict = json["services"].arrayValue.first else { return }`

Comment: but its not always the first service it must be an index. heres the idea i got a list of UIPickerViews based on the number of services and the option of those picker views is the properties of the services so the user can pick multiple properties for a single service the user also can leave out the first service and select the third pickerviews options so i cant be sure which service will be selected i must the selected index

Comment: heres another thought can i put a conditional statement on the properties parameter something like this `properties: dict["properties][someIndex]["id"].stringValue == someId ? dict["properties"].arrayValue.map : " "`

Comment: About the first comment you can pass the index you want instead of using "first".
And if you check the documentation of the SwiftyJSON library: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON you can replace the `stringValue` with the optional `string`. Anyway if this helped you you can mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check previous service id:

```
if loadedServices.contains { (element) -> Bool in
        element.id == currentService.id
    }) == false { 
        // unique
        loadedServices.append(currentService)
        ...
    } else { 

    }
```